# Create Taxonomy sub-term using CSOM and javascript

Tags: javascript, taxonomy, sharepoint-2013, csom

in sharepoint managed metadata I found very little documentation on managing terms using javascript CSOM. I could create a taxonomy term directly under the term set but I want to create a term under another term as a child like in term store window.

```
function createTerm(){
//Current Context
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
//Current Taxonomy Session
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
//Term Stores
var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
//Term Store under which to create the term.
var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Dmxzz8tIBzk8wNVKQpJ+xA==");
//Term Set under which to create the term.
var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");
//Name of the term, LCID and a new GUID for the term.
var newTerm = termSet.createTerm("India", 1033, "b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344a9");
//newTerm.set_isAvailableForTagging(true);
context.load(newTerm);
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
alert("Term Created: " + newTerm.get_name());
 },function(sender,args){
console.log(args.get_message());
});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add term under a parent term, you need:

- The Term store ID and relevant Term set
- The Parent Term ID (to which the new child term will be added)

The code:

```
 function execOperation()
 {
    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

    //Term Store under which to create the term.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Dmxzz8tIBzk8wNVKQpJ+xA==");

    //Term Set under which to create the term.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");


    //get the parent term ID, say it's "cf46hujkl-3344-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4"
    var parentTerm = termSet.getTerm("cf46hujkl-3344-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");

    //create new child term under the parent term
    var newTerm = parentTerm.createTerm("SharePoint Rocks", 1033, newGuid.toString());

    context.load(newTerm);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    alert("Term Created: " + newTerm.get_name());
     },function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
    });}
```